# commerce_line_item VS field_data_commerce_line_items

Tags: 7, commerce, database

Right now, I am touching the database for drupal 7. I searched about the difference between "commerce_line_item" table and "field_data_commerce_line_items" table. But no luck.

Does anyone know the difference between them? Also, is there any reference that I can follow to check the table explanation?

I really appreciate anyone's help.

**UPDATE**

Based on everyone's help and my own opinion, I drew a simple diagram for these two tables:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`commerce_line_item` is the base table of entity with same name. The entity is defined from the sub module **commerce_line_item** in [Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) project. You can find the definition from its code repository

[**commerce_line_item.module**](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce/tree/modules/line_item/commerce_line_item.module?h=7.x-1.13)

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_info().
 */
function commerce_line_item_entity_info() {
  $return = array(
    'commerce_line_item' => array(
      'label' => t('Commerce Line item'),
      'controller class' => 'CommerceLineItemEntityController',
      'base table' => 'commerce_line_item',
      'fieldable' => TRUE,
      'entity keys' => array(
        'id' => 'line_item_id',
        'bundle' => 'type',
        'label' => 'line_item_id', // TODO: Update to use a custom callback.
      ),
      ...
```

[**commerce_line_item.install**](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce/tree/modules/line_item/commerce_line_item.install?h=7.x-1.13)

```php
function commerce_line_item_schema() {
  $schema = array();

  $schema['commerce_line_item'] = array(
    'description' => 'The base table for line items.',
    'fields' => array(
      'line_item_id' => array( ... ),
      'order_id' => array( ... ),
      'type' => array( ... ),
      'line_item_label' => array( ... ),
      'quantity' => array( ... ),
      'created' => array( ... ),
      'changed' => array( ... ),
      'data' => array( ... ),
    ),

    ...
```

---

`field_data_commerce_line_items` is a field created by **commerce_order**, which is another sub module in [Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) module during installation. You can find this behaviour here

[**commerce_order.module**](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce/tree/modules/order/commerce_order.module?h=7.x-1.13)

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_modules_enabled().
 */
function commerce_order_modules_enabled($modules) {
  commerce_order_configure_order_fields($modules);

  ...
}

/**
 * Ensures the line item field is present on the default order bundle.
 */
function commerce_order_configure_order_type($type = 'commerce_order') {
  // Look for or add a line item reference field to the order type.
  $field_name = 'commerce_line_items';
  commerce_activate_field($field_name);
  field_cache_clear();

  $field = field_info_field($field_name);
  $instance = field_info_instance('commerce_order', $field_name, $type);

  if (empty($field)) {
    $field = array(
      'field_name' => $field_name,
      'type' => 'commerce_line_item_reference',
      'cardinality' => FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED,
      'entity_types' => array('commerce_order'),
      'translatable' => FALSE,
      'locked' => TRUE,
    );
    $field = field_create_field($field);
  }

  ...
```

Please note that the field type here is `commerce_line_item_reference`, which is defined in `commerce_line_item` module as well.

[**commerce_line_item.install**](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce/tree/modules/line_item/commerce_line_item.install?h=7.x-1.13)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_schema().
 */
function commerce_line_item_field_schema($field) {
  if ($field['type'] == 'commerce_line_item_reference') {
    return array(
      'columns' => array(
        'line_item_id' => array(
          'type' => 'int',
          'unsigned' => TRUE,
          'not null' => FALSE,
        ),
      ),
      'indexes' => array(
        'line_item_id' => array('line_item_id'),
      ),
      'foreign keys' => array(
        'line_item_id' => array(
          'table' => 'commerce_line_item',
          'columns' => array('line_item_id' => 'line_item_id'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

According to the schema defined above, `commerce_line_item_reference` acts exactly similar as a entity reference, which helps each **order** can be connected to a number of **line items**.

Comment: I know it's a long time ago topic. But right now, I am a little confused that which table will actually store orders' information?

Comment: @jmu What kind of information you want from order?

Comment: I think I got it. I want some detailed information. commerce_line_item is the table I need to look at.

Comment: @jmu cool. have a Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 1):

My answer concerns the structural and not the semantic difference between the two.

The table field_data_commerce_line_items corresponds to a standard drupal field. On the other hand commerce_line_item is a table that is managed by one of the modules in the commerce module family.

The table field_config_instance describes the relationships between drupal fields (which are actually tables such as field_data_commerce_line_items) and higher level entity types (i.e. node) and bundles (i.e. content type) that reference them.